# How to share functions cross files in coffeescript when developing chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, coffeescript

Coffeescript wraps each file in a anonymous closure. When I want to write a global function, I have to assign it to window:

```
func = -> alert("hello world")
windows.func = func
```

or in Node.js, to export:

```
func = -> alert("hello world")
export.func = func
```

But how about chrome extension? How to share functions in background page to other pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not share functions/data like that, but I guess you could load the same code in both pages if you just need to run certain functions and not share data. If you need to communicate with your background page, you need to use the proper messaging functions, see:

[how can i use the port.postmessage to send info from the background page to the content script in a google chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936643/how-can-i-use-the-port-postmessage-to-send-info-from-the-background-page-to-the)

Comment: how to "load the same code"? Does javascript provide the load or require feature?

Comment: Anyway, I used messaging to solve my problem. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage) API to access functions in the background page. For example:

```
var bp = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
bp.func();
```